# Moment in node js gives +5.30 hrs from ms-sql server but it works fine with mysql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, node.js

/*function i am using*/

```
let parseDate = function (rows){
    for (let key in rows[0]) {
        if(key.indexOf('_dtm') > -1 && rows[0][key] `checking for datetime cols`!== undefined && rows[0][key] !== null){
            rows[0][key] = moment(new Date(rows[0][key])).format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss');
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
```

/*moment in nodejs gives +5.30 hrs from ms-sql server but it works fine with mysql server*/

Comment: Are you sure the date `rows[0][key]` coming from the databases is not different ? Or it changes after `moment` formats it ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev its coming from data base only m just formatting and it works seemlessly for mysql but not for mssql   msql-sql("Thu, 22 Feb 2018 19:28:55"), mysql ("Thu, 22 Feb 2018 13:58:55")

Comment: You're missing the point. It's very likely that the dates coming from the databases are different. You should look at the value of `rows[0][key]` without moment. And that is probably because of how the databases are configured.

Comment: @BrahmaDev it worked   moment(new Date(rows[0][key])).utcOffset('+0000').format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss');